# Can different versions of cmake yield to different results?

Tags: linux, cmake, compiler-errors

I have two different linux environments each of which contains cmake version 3.14.0-rc3 and 3.13.0.

When I built the same source code on each environment, the binary files resulted in totally different results.

Can it be caused by different versions of cmake? If yes, what should be conisdered to prevent differences.

Comment: 1) I hate cmake, vastly prefer "make" and so can't really talk about cmake per se.  BUT ... 2) As long as you're on the SAME PLATFORM, with the SAME COMPILER, using the SAME COMPILER FLAGS ... then how/why could cmake version possibly matter?  ALSO: Q: How to prevent the differences?  A: Use "docker" for your builds might be one very good solution.

Comment: "totally different results" - What is actually differs? Paths of the source files or linker, compiled into the binaries? Different code? Or what? Please, elaborate that.

Comment: Examine the build log (make VERBOSE=1). If the compiler invocations are different, the result maybe different